# Going Thru Customs

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit, qatar-airways, qatar, doha

I am looking to book a round trip flight from the San Francisco to Nairobi.  I have a connecting fight for both the outbound and return trips.  All segments of this trip are on the same airline. Do I have to go thru customs for this leg of the flight?  I know I will have to go thru customs upon landing in San Francisco but not sure about Doha.

Comment: Hi Felecia, welcome to travel stack exchange! What airline specifically are you flying, and at what airports are your connections?

Comment: Typically you will pass through both customs and immigration (two separate things which may sometimes be combined into a single official) when you arrive in a different country. There are some exceptions where you might go through "pre-clearance" for the arriving country as you depart the previous one, but in general it happens when you arrive in the new country.

Comment: @brhans On *arrival*, yes, but usually not when connecting, and the OP is asking about connecting via Qatar (Doha).

Answer (score 3):

If this is a single ticket issued by Qatar airlines you do NOT need to go through immigration or customs in Doha. You do NOT need a Visa or access credentials for Qatar.

You DO have to go through security again.

Comment: Note for future readers: while this is true in Doha and many other airports when you are connecting between flights on the same ticket, this is not universally true in other places.

Comment: @jcaron: I don't think ANYTHING is universally true for international travel :-)